# How to change default table wp_option to wp_sitemeta in redux framework on wordpress?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, redux-framework

Currently I am editing on plugins which used redux framework to save data but it is by default saving in `wp_options` table while I need to save into it `wp_sitemeta` table.

I checked all the option but not getting table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoiler alert, lead dev here at ReduxFramework.

Interesting. We just use the get_option and update_option functions.

One way would be to use the validation callback and update that as well on your own on every save.

If you wanted, we have 2 functions inside function.php. One is set_options and the other is, you guessed it, get_options. We COULD add an override hook in there and let you override those functions to do whatever you want for them.

I don't know the use case here, but it sounds like it would be better for you to get the community talking on the Redux issue tracker found here: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/issues

Then we can see if it's something the community wants.